# db2 create failing with SQL1762N

Tags: database, db2

db2 V10.5 RedHat Linux RHEL7. Installed without error.

db2 create db AMW907 on /home/mis/amw907 fails with

SQL1762N Unable to connect to database because there is not enough space to allocate active log files. SQLSTATE=08004

My disk space is good

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/rhel-root 50G 9.6G 41G 20% / devtmpfs 32G 0 32G 0% /dev tmpfs 32G 8.0K 32G 1% /dev/shm tmpfs 32G 28M 32G 1% /run tmpfs 32G 0 32G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup /dev/sda2 1014M 163M 852M 17% /boot /dev/sda1 200M 9.9M 191M 5% /boot/efi /dev/mapper/rhel-home 1.8T 41G 1.7T 3% /home

A directory monitor shows all the create activity but at the it all sel deletes.

Comment: Are you able to run `touch /home/mis/amw907/test.txt` successfully, and what's the result of `ulimit -f` (both from the db2 instance owner)? Do you have disk quotas?

Comment: Yes to the touch command. ulimit is unlimited.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by disk quotas?

Comment: [disk qoutas](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-disk-quotas). What’s the SELinux status? Can you disable it and retry, if it’s not disabled?

Comment: Disk quotas are not in use. Disabling selinux had no affect.

Comment: Apparently this is my issue

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449214